# concatinate numpy matrices to get an array with dimension 3

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I want to concatenate numpy matrices that have different shapes in order to get an array with dimension=3.
example :

```
A= [[2 1 3 4]
    [2 4 0 6]
    [9 5 7 4]]
B= [[7 2 8 4]
    [8 6 8 6]]
```

and result what I need should be like that:

```
C=[[[2 1 3 4]
    [2 4 0 6]
    [9 5 7 4]]
   [[7 2 8 4]
    [8 6 8 6]]]
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, a 3dim numpy array is probably not the way to represent your data, because there's no definitive *shape*.

A 3dim numpy array should have a shape of the form N1 x N2 x N3, whereas in your case each "2dim row" has a different shape.

Alternatives would be to keep your data in lists (or a list of arrays), or to use [masked arrays](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.html), if that happens to be reasonable in you case.

Comment: yes you are right sorry, shouldn't be a 3 d numpy array! may be would be better to say I'm looking for to have an array of matrices or to concatenate different matrices having different shapes

Answer (score 0):

You can only convert to a 3D `np.ndarray` in a useful manner if `A.shape == B.shape`. In that case all you need to do is e.g. `C = np.array([A, B])`.

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([[2, 1, 3, 4],
              [9, 5, 7, 4]])
B = np.array([[7, 2, 8, 4],
              [8, 6, 8, 6]])

C = np.array([A, B])
print C
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `A` and `B` have different sizes (# of rows), the best you can do make an array of shape `(2,)` and dtype `object`.  Or at least that's what a simple construction gives you:

```
In [9]: np.array([A,B])
Out[9]: 
array([array([[2, 1, 3, 4],
       [2, 4, 0, 6],
       [9, 5, 7, 4]]),
       array([[7, 2, 8, 4],
       [8, 6, 8, 6]])], dtype=object)
```

But constructing an array like this doesn't help much.  Just use the list `[A,B]`.

`np.vstack([A,B])` produces a `(5,4)` array.

`np.array([A[:2,:],B])` gives a `(2,2,4)` array.  Or you could pad `B` so they are both `(3,4)`.

So one way or other you need to redefine your problem.